# Call method again after a delay in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

We have a WCF that uploads files to SharePoint once a day. If the file name contains any data that doesn't match some data in SharePoint, it gets rejected and moved to a rejected folder (and logs that rejection) while the accepted files is uploaded to SharePoint.

Sometimes the rejected files is rejected 'without a reason' (not because of mismatch with data in SharePoint), it could be that ShP has anykind of downtime while the WCF is running. This causes some confusion (the expected reason is that the file name doesnt match with ShP data, but no).

We want the WCF to try the rejected files again with a delay then run the method again, if it fails then, then it should be moved (and logged) to the rejected folder.

The WCF call:

```
 [OperationContract]
    void ExecuteFileImport();
```

And the Method ExecuteFileImport

```
//The files.AcceptedFiles have already sorted out the files that have correct file name format
//(eg. File1_20161010_version1.docx, it rejects the file if it has eg. File120161010_version1.docs)

foreach (var file in files.AcceptedFiles)
{
    //..... Some logic to compare the file name to ShP list item data

        try
        {
            this.SharePointHandler.AddFileToShPList(file, dataFromShPList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.ErrorMessages.Add(ex, file.fileName);

                // Moves the file to rejected folder.

                //Here (or in the try block) I want to try the AddFileToShPList again with delay if it fails
                // (ShP down, patching, metadata service is down etc) before moving the file to rejected folder

        }

}
```

It has happend a few times that when ShP is being patched and the WCF is running, it moves the files to the rejected folder for that reason.

Is this possible to solve?

Comment: Are there two different exception types for times when sharepoint is down and when the file does not match?

Comment: Removed the second try-block

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file with the name rejected.txt
2. Add the rejected file names to the file on the server
3. Process each filename listed in the file name as the first step in the execution of the file import to the share point